# Does std::find use operator== for std::vector<std::pair<T, T>>?

Tags: iterator, find, std, operator-keyword, predicate

I tried to overload operator== for std::pair<int, int> so that only the first element of the pair would matter. Then, I'd like to use std::find to look for a particular element in std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>, using the overloaded operator==. But, it seems that, std::find is not using my overloaded operator==, though it is working in a simple comparison statement.

I expect the following code to output:
1
1
1

but I get:
1
1
0

Run on Linux, gcc 11.3:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> p_int_t;

bool operator==(const p_int_t& p1, const p_int_t& p2)
{
    return p1.first == p2.first;
}

int main()
{
    vector<p_int_t> v;

    v.push_back({1, 2});
    v.push_back({1, 3});

    p_int_t p(1, 4);

        cout << (v[0] == p) << endl;
    cout << (v[1] == p) << endl;

        cout << (find(v.begin(), v.end(), p) != v.end()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not select the free standing comparison operator because the type p_int_t is an alias, and it is not defined in the std namespace as std:: pair is.  In other words, the compiler is looking for an operator with this signature: `std::operator==(const std::pair<int, int>&, const std::pair<int, int>&);` and finds it in `algorithm`.

You could declare your operator in the std namespace, which works, but is not recommended, or define p_int_t as a class, as in:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct p_int_t : pair<int, int> {

    using pair<int, int>::pair;   // for c++=11 and later

    p_int_t() : pair() {}                 // for c++98
    p_int_t(int x, int y) : pair(x, y) {} // for c++98

    friend bool operator==(const p_int_t& p1, const p_int_t& p2) {
        return p1.first == p2.first;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<p_int_t> v;

    v.push_back({1, 2});
    v.push_back({1, 3});

    p_int_t p(1, 4);

    cout << (v[0] == p) << endl;
    cout << (v[1] == p) << endl;

    cout << (find(v.begin(), v.end(), p) != v.end()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Code can be found here: https://godbolt.org/z/5dfPaaoMz

Having to redefine constructors is quite cumbersome, but you can also use std::find_if(), as in:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> p_int_t;

struct compare_first {
    p_int_t p;

    compare_first(p_int_t x) : p(x) {}
    bool operator()(const p_int_t& x) { return x.first == p.first; }
};

int main() {
    vector<p_int_t> v;

    v.push_back({1, 2});
    v.push_back({1, 3});

    p_int_t p(1, 4);

    cout << (find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), compare_first(p)) != v.end()) << endl;

    // or for c++11 or later...

    cout << (find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&p](const p_int_t& x) { return p.first == x.first; }) != v.end()) << endl;
     

    return 0;
}
```

Code here: https://godbolt.org/z/r87hdrrK9